# How to Find the Chunks for a Webpack Entry

Tags: javascript, webpack, webforms, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-splitchunks

I'm using webpack to modernize a legacy multiple-page ASP.NET Web Forms application.  I've had pretty good success with it up till I tried using the [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) to de-dupe my bundles using its `chunks: 'all'` option.  This unfortunately makes a handful of extra JS bundles that all need to be included in `script` tags along with the original entry bundle.  No surprise, the above linked doc states as much:

> By default [the plugin] only affects on-demand chunks, because changing initial chunks would affect the script tags the HTML file should include to run the project.

But I would very much like to have those initial entry chunks split up, so I'm trying to find a way of getting all those extra chunks included in script tags.  It seems the standard advice here is to use the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to generate an HTML page with all the script tags included, but this doesn't work for me (at least in its default configuration) for at least two reasons:

1. This is a Web Forms project. One does not simply tamper with aspx files.
2. Even if I did find a way to generate some valid aspx files every time I ran webpack (I suppose that's doable, but here is the main difficulty); it seems HtmlWebpackPlugin only generates script tags for *all* the chunks, or a manually selected subset of them (using the `chunks: []` option).

To elaborate on that second point, and get to my question -- I could do some manual analysis of the split chunks to build a dependency graph and manually include each one in the aspx, but that's obviously not a maintainable approach.  I was hoping HtmlWebpackPlugin could offer some way of at least indicating that this chunk is ultimately used by this entry, or this entry uses these chunks, etc., but I have not found any such relationships present in its output.

Is there any way without going through hack-hoops to automatically determine which of the split chunks are dependencies of a given entry chunk?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? You seem to be the only other person I’ve seen with this problem, even though it seems like a fairly basic use case

Answer (score 6):

#### Install this plugin with option to your webpack config:

`npm install webpack-manifest-plugin --save-dev`

```js
// webpack.config.js

const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')

concatMerge(configuration, {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'prod.manifest.json',
      generate: (seed, files) => {
        const entrypoints = new Set()
        files.forEach(
          (file) => ((file.chunk || {})._groups || []).forEach(
            (group) => entrypoints.add(group)
          )
        )
        const entries = [...entrypoints]
        const entryArrayManifest = entries.reduce((acc, entry) => {
          const name = (entry.options || {}).name
            || (entry.runtimeChunk || {}).name
          const files = [].concat(
            ...(entry.chunks || []).map((chunk) => chunk.files)
          ).filter(Boolean)
          return name ? {...acc, [name]: files} : acc
        }, seed)
        return entryArrayManifest
      }
    }),
  ],
}
```

#### It will generate a `prod.manifest.json` contain chunks for every entry or routes:

```json
{
  "entryOne": [
    "main.common.d7791ce7a1e7ba394.css",
    "main.common.d7791ce7a1e7ba394.js",
    "main.entryOne.eb614be915641d465.js"
  ],
  "a-route": [
    "main.common.d7791ce7a1e7ba394.css",
    "main.a-routes.14b91be915641d465.js"
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simply, for the same result as @Junior Tour you can also use the `entries` parameter of the `generate` property:

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackManifestPlugin(
    {
        fileName: 'prod.manifest.json',
        generate: (seed, files, entries) => {
            return entries;
        }
    }),
],
```