# webpack get all dependencies for splitchunk

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am using SplitChunksPlugin plugin to reduce the size of my entry js file, and to allow caching of individual dependencies that are shared over multiple entries. Currently, I am manually loading dependencies in html code.

Are there any plugins or way to parse the resultant chunk file to find all the dependencies?

Comment: See the answer here. Works for webpack 5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69331449/1901035